# Button written in html code does not call the javascript function when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

i am working on a project for my college but i can't seem to get it working correctly. i have written a button in html and the function in javascript. My button doesnt seem to call the procedure when clicked, i inserted a alert just to make sure of that. When i comment out my code the alert pops up just fine, but as soon as i uncomment my block of code the button doesnt seem to work at all, in fact when i uncomment the code, my whole javascript seems to fail since another button i wrote wont work either.
Any ideas why that would be, or what i did wrong?

Code HTML :

```
<Div Align="Center" id="Next">
  <Br>
  <Br>
  <Br>
  <Br>
  <Br>
  <Br>
  <Br>
  <Br>
  <Br>
  <Br>

  <Input Type="Button" Value="Next" onClick="Next()">
</Div>
```

Code Javascript :

```
function Next(){
  alert('P');

  Image = Image++;
  If (Image = 1){
    document.getElementsByClassName(Images).setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img1.jpg');
  } else if {
    (Image = 2){
    document.getElementsByClassName(Images).setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img2.jpg');
  }} else if {
    (Image = 3){
    document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img3.JPEG');
  }} else if {
    (Image = 4){
    document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img4.png');
  }} else if {
    (Image = 5){
    document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img5.jpg');
  }} else if {
    (Image = 6){
    document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img6.jpg');
  }} else if {
    (Image = 7){
    document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img7.jpg');
  }} else if {
    (Image = 8){
    document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img8.jpg');
  }} else if {
    (Image = 9){
    document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img9.jpg');
}}}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any error in console log?

Comment: check inside your conditions! :)

Comment: you got an error ` Unexpected token {`

Comment: Imagine what mayhem would ensue if you got educated about the delights of a switch statement

Comment: `}} else if {` should change to `} else if {`

Comment: what about `document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img' + Image + '.jpg');` ?

Comment: Yeah we'll be getting to learn switches in a week or so. I'm using notepad++ for the coding and unfortunatedly it doesnt have a debugger

Comment: @Frederik.L - That is heresy.

Comment: @TH3SN3R - The browser does

Comment: Try doing indentation in your code. You would have solved that yourself If you had done the indentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are always assigning, not comparing

```
if (Image = 1)
```

assigns -

```
if (Image == 1)
```

would compare.

Second, the entire thing can be rewritten to

```
function Next(){
    Image = Image++;
    document.getElementById('Image').setAttribute('src', '\Christopher_Thesner_HTML_Formative_1\Img\Img' + Image + '.jpg');
}
```

as you're only setting the image src to whatever number your `Image` variable is holding.

Also change your html to use an `ID` for the image.

```
<img src="" id="Image">
```

Comment: ` document.getElementsByClassName('Images').setAttribute` will throw an error because `setAttribute` is not a function.

Comment: I see what you mean. And i just edited my code to your suggestion. The button does call the function perfectly now, but the images still wont change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
var Img=0;
function Next(){
    Img = Img+1;
    document.getElementById("Image").src = "http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Image"+Img;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="Next()">Change Image</button>
<img id="Image">
```